# Maclaurin series for ln(1+x)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to calculate in c++ the value of ln(1+x) using the Maclaurin series: x-x^2/2+x^3/3-...+(-1)^(n+1)*x^2n/2n. But if I insert a number larger than 2, the program will return the error nan.

My code is here:

```
double ln(double x){
 double oldx=x,prec,t=x,i=1,eps=0.0001; 

int semn=-1;

 do{ prec=x;

  t=t*oldx;

    i++;
    x=prec+(t/i)*semn;
    semn=-semn;

 }while(fabs(x-prec)>=eps);

return x;
}
```

What can I do to get the right answer?

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: yeah, I can't find the error. I think that the growth of the exponential is too fast to be "stopped" by a simple division.

Comment: If you had stepped through your code with a debugger, there would be no need to "think", what the issue is - you would **know**.

Comment: 1) It's more helpful if you paste up compilable code, 2) The issues occur when you exceed the *radius of convergence*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an error in your program, you're using the Maclaurin series outside of its validity range. The convergence radius of this Taylor series is 1, so you'll ever get ln(1+x) out of it for |x| < 1. See the image in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative,_Taylor_series) of Wikipedia, where it's clear that the approximation fails in a way that adding more terms will not help.

Power series always converge on a disk (in complex plane) that stops before it can reach any singularity, and is infinite only if the function is [entire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function). The function ln(1+x) diverges to minus infinity for x = -1, so the radius can be (at most) one. It can be determined to be exactly that using more rigorous methods. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Taylor series doesn't converge for any number larger than 2, in other words Taylor series for ln(1+x) doesn't converge for x > 1. You can find actual radius of convergence with [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). The formula is

[image]